# Download over remote root server directly to home system

Tags: remote, file-transfer

I have to download some big data from a source that needs a static IP. As at home I only have a dynamic IP that won't work. So I thought about using my rent remote root server to download the data. But the data is so large that I can't use the root server as intermediate storage. I have to download the data directly to my home pc, but somehow over the root server (so that the download source only sees the root servers static IP).
What is the way to go? Is it a simple SSH command from my home system? Or do I have to install something special? (Maybe a pretty easy question, but networking isn't my field of activity)

Regards,
Kai

Comment: Can you provide a few more details?  What OS are you using on the local machine?  What OS is on the remote machine ("root server")?  How do you connect from the local machine to the remote machine (ssh?)?

Knowing these answers will help us come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps a little hokey, but what about using wget piped into nc (this is of course assuming you have a *nix-type machine both on the remote host and your home system).

On your home system:

```
$ nc -l [port_number] > filename.foo
```

And then on your remote system:

```
$ wget http://your.url.com/filename.foo -O - | nc [ip_of_home_system] [port_number]
```

Where [port_number] is a TCP port of your liking that can get through any firewall(s) you may have in place.  I haven't tried this personally, but it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You might try bouncing off a proxy on a machine with a static IP, such as squid.

Better yet, if you have SSH access to *any* machine with a static IP, you can use the SOCKS option for SSH:

```
ssh -D localhost:8888 user@remotehost
```

Then you configure your browser or download tool to use the SOCKS4 or SOCKS5 proxy and feed it port 8888 at localhost.  No intermediate storage required.